# Insert a specific row in a CSV file, Not replacing other values in Python

Tags: python

I want to insert a string in a certain row, via String and Number of Position 
From:

```
Str1
Str2
Str3
```

To

```
Str1
Str2
Inserted String
Str3
```

I have done much research, some replaces the value, so it was of no use, any ideas how to go about it? New from python, I tried translating my code from C++, but its kind of hard to do it in this language.

My code so far:

```
sk= raw_input("\nWhat SKU would you like to insert?: ")
pos= int(raw_input("\nAt what row?: "))


f = open("files.csv","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
print(row[pos])
f = open("files.csv","w")

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(line[pos]):
        line[pos] = sk
f.close()
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a line-wise text file, then this would be a way to do it.

```
sk= raw_input("\nWhat SKU would you like to insert?: ")
pos= int(raw_input("\nAt what row?: "))

with open("files.csv","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines.insert(pos, sk + '\n')

with open("files.csv","w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Using `with` always closes files, even in case of errors or other unexpected events (the [`with` statement manages contexts](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), not only for file handlers). Then, simply insert the item into the list and write the list back.

If you don't want to modify the list in-memory, you could [use the built-in enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the second for-loop:

```
with open("files.csv","w") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == pos:
            f.write(sk + '\n')
        f.write(line)
```

But if you want to manipulate the CSV data in some way, you could [just `import csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Wow, thanks! didn't know there was actually a built-in for that, but I got another problem. the (files+ '\n'). I tried the program with a larger file, and when it ran, in the CSV, it skips a field(well I know that this was caused by the '\n') and when I delete it, when i insert something it concat's to the existing in that row, is there a way to make this not skip a row?

Instead of

SKU-111

SKU-333

SKU-222

to

SKU-111
SKU-333
SKU-222

Comment: You are correct, [the docs for `file.readline()` say:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) "trailing newline character is kept in the string". So there is no need to add it when writing previous lines back to the files. Only when inserting the new string. I will update the answer.